# Python: Return Accuracy with % sign

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 print("k = %d, Accuracy = %d" % (k, accuracy))
```

This line of code returns

k = 15, Accuracy = 95

How would I make it so it returns

k = 15, Accuracy = 95%

Answer (score 1):

create a string variable for % and then use it in place of trying to %, which doesn't work

```
k = 15
accuracy = 95
perc = '%'

print('k = %i, accuracy = %i' % (k,accuracy), perc)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCzaM.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the `%` with extra %.

```
print("k = %d, Accuracy = %d%%" % (15, 95))
k = 15, Accuracy = 95%
```

Answer (score 0):

you can even use f strings

```
f"k ={variable}, Accuracy = {variable}%"
```